# setTimeout/setInterval with multiple delays to execute code

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout, delay, setinterval

I have an array with multiple delays stored in it: `myArray[8000,4000,3000,6000,5000]`. I need for `setTimeout`/`setInterval` to run each delay and then execute a specific piece of code. So for example:

```
myArray[0]=8000;
myArray[1]=4000;
myArray[2]=3000;
myArray[3]=6000;
myArray[4]=5000;

for(var k=0;k<5;k++)
{
    setTimeout(function() {

console.log("CODE TO BE EXECUTED");

    }, diffArray[k]);
}
```

So the end result would be wait 12 seconds run code, wait 4 seconds run code, wait 3 seconds run code wait 6 seconds run code, and wait 5 seconds and run code. The current code runs them all at the same time.

I know that this most likely needs to be done with recursion, I've tried a few things as far as getting it to work, but no luck. I got it to work one way but it unfortunately locked the UI thread which I will need to perform other actions in the UI while this is running. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not seeing a big problem with your code. (except that `diffArray` should probably be `myArray`....)

Comment: It should be "result would be wait *8* seconds to run code", no?

Answer (score 4):

Run setTimeout sequentially. You are running all setTimeout at same time.

```
myArray[0]=8000;
myArray[1]=4000;
myArray[2]=3000;
myArray[3]=6000;
myArray[4]=5000;
var k =0;
    function repeat(){
       if(k == myArray.length) return;
      setTimeout(function() {
              repeat();
              console.log("CODE TO BE EXECUTED");

      }, myArray[k]);
     k++;
  }
```

Comment: Then you should mark this as the answer @user830524

Answer (score 0):

You should make another function so that the k variable is copied each time because setTimeout is an async operation:

```
var func = function(k)
{
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("CODE TO BE EXECUTED");
    }, diffArray[k]);
}

for(var k=0;k<5;k++)
{
  func(k)
}
```

Comment: This won't change/fix a thing here. `diffArray[k]` already evaluated to a value before `setTimeout(..)` was invoked so there was no issue with `k` caught in a closure; the original issue of not running "in sequence" still remains.

Answer (score 0):

You mention 12 seconds, but there is not a value that large.  If you want the code to run 8sec, 12sec,15sec,21sec, and 26sec, then:

```
var delay =0;
for(var k=0;k<5;k++){
   delay+=myArray[k];
   setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("CODE TO BE EXECUTED");
   }, delay);
}
```